# Invalid DVDs on home player

Tags: dvd, brasero, k3b

DVDs ripped and burned with native Linux apps are "invalid" in my home DVD player, using DVDshrink or DVDfab through wine will yield a playable disc? I figure its something simple I've got set up wrong but all my searches I've found no solution.

Answer (score 0):

probably you have burned with wrong type. Generally dvd burned with video DVD but now-a-days DVD players are able to play dvd burned with DATA DVD. If you can use your writer in Wine then you can create dvd using DVDshrink, DVDfab or nero through Wine.

Edit:- You can find alternatives for any platform [here](http://alternativeto.net/)

Comment: Yeah I can make perfectly playable discs with dvdshrink and dvdfab I can even burn files created with those programs with native Linux burners. But if I create the files with say K9 or DVD95 the discs come out invalid. OGMrip freezes 90% of the way through a rip, xdvdshrink won't do subtitles. I'd just really like to use native Linux apps but I've been unable top find any solutions.

Comment: Update: If I tell DVD95 to create its output as an .iso and burn the .iso, the output is playable. With K9 if I uncheck the "use dvdauthor for copy without menus" box and have it create .iso's those will also create playable discs. this leads me to belive there's a problem with dvdauthors configuration but I don't know enough about it to fix it. xdvdshrink still wont do DVD subtitles which is unfortunate as it seems to be capable of ripping even where windozz programs fail. Hope this is useful to others.